# Can I install Ubuntu on an external hard drive and make it bootable from any other computer?

Tags: boot, 13.10, external-hdd

As the title mentioned, please give some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu
follow instructions if you are using linux atm

if you are using windows you can use unetbootin or any other iso to usb software

Comment: I mean can I install and boot it from other computer? I installed it but it can't be booted from other computer

Comment: Ahh no i dont think you can make any changes while in dvd or usb mode

Comment: So it is impossible to make it bootable from different computers?